# socket.io giving me weird output

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io

when i restart my server i see the weird output.. could you clarify why i am getting this output.By seeing network in developer tool in chrome i found every time it is making a request. My goal was to test socket disconnection as soon as possible that's why i set heartbeat interval and heartbeat timeout.

my server side code is as===>>>

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.set('heartbeat interval',10);
io.set('heartbeat timeout',25);
io.set('transports',  'xhr-polling');
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var currentdate = new Date(); 
  var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                  + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                  + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                  + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                  + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                  + currentdate.getSeconds();
  console.log("connection established...!!!" + datetime);
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("disconnection established...!!!");
  });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and the output is 
1). i started server
2). client connected
3).  i cleared console
4). i closed server and again restarted.

and the output after restarting server is this. Can anybody tell me why it is happening.There are so many multiple connection and disconnection with only one client.

```
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:11:37
disconnection established...!!!
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:11:40
disconnection established...!!!
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:11:47
disconnection established...!!!
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:11:54
disconnection established...!!!
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:12:14
disconnection established...!!!
connection established...!!!Last Sync: 11/11/2014 @ 8:12:35
disconnection established...!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your client side code. Please take a look at the following code. It is working. 
Server side code-'chat.js'

```
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log('a user connected');
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
 });
 socket.on('chat_message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
 });
  socket.emit("progress",90);
});

http.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:5000');
});
```

And the client side code goes here.'index.html'

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
    <button id="btn">Send</button>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('#btn').click(function(e) {
        console.log('ok');
        //e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat_message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat_message', function(msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
    socket.on("progress", function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But you have not used heartbeat timeout and heartbeat interval... it occurs when you set both of these values. do restart you will get above following output. The main problem is i just want to set heartbeat timeout and interval ..as i followed the condition that timeout value should be greater than heartbeat interval. How can i use both of these and get correct result.